# How to Display this CSS List using Class

Tags: html, css

Is there any way I can mimic this list in CSS? I want to have a class that centers the list, remove the black dot in the unordered list. In fact, I want it exactly the same as the image below.

[image]

I have a column of 250px and would like the whole list aligned to the middle of the 250px column, not just each list item otherwise any shorter link will move into the center a step-like list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your list is left aligned right?

Comment: If you aren't confident with css/html I would suggest reading through the tutorials on http://HTMLDog.com otherwise try to inculde some code/example code as it is quite hard for us to help you fix code that we can't see.

Comment: Look at the second example on this link. It'll give you what you need. http://pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list-style-type:none;` will remove the dot from the list.
The color is simple `color:red;` (or any other color)
It seems bold so `font-weight:bold;`
If you want to capitalize also, use `text-transform:capitalize;`
All together its:

```
ul.classname {
    list-style-type:none;
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

I don't understand what you mean by "centers the list"...

Comment: Would center on a table cell be `text-align:center`? (iirc)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to float your UL (since you don't know the size of the list).
[This page tells you how to center floated items](http://pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm).